How to replace multiple values in a single row with dictionary in pyspark?
I have a column called fruits. each row has format in this format ["apple","banana","mango"]. I have a dictionary which has {oldvalue:newvalue}. I want to replace apple with eg grapes. How to do it in pyspark?
What i tried
df_silver_3 = df_silver_2.filter(F.col("fruits").isNotNull())\
    .withColumn("fruits_cleaned", regexp_replace(df_silver_2["fruits"].cast("string"), r"[\[\]]", ""))\
    .select("fruits", "fruits_cleaned")

replacement dictionary
replace_dict = {
    "apple": "grapes",  
    "value2": "replacement2"
}

Replacing values in the 'fruits_cleaned' column using the dictionary
df_replaced = df_silver_3.select(
    [when(col("fruits_cleaned") == key, value).otherwise(col("fruits_cleaned")).alias("fruits_cleaned") for key, value in replace_dict.items()] + 
    [col("fruits")]  # Include original column if needed
)

What i was expecting
I was expecting that apple would be replaced by grapes
["apple","banana","mango"] -> ["grapes","banana","mango"]

You can make use of expr and transform to achieve your requirement.
Build the expression like below using above functions to replace the array with required dictionary values:
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

my_dict = {"apple": "grapes", "mango": "orange"}
req_exp =  "transform(fruits, a -> CASE "  +  " ".join([f"WHEN a = '{x}' THEN '{y}'"  for x, y in my_dict.items()]) +  " ELSE a END)"

res_df = df.withColumn("fruits_cleaned", expr(req_exp))

res_df.show()

Result:

